# .htaccess changes from 2.2 to 2.4, protect directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I have a web server running Apache 2.2 and am starting a new one with Apache 2.4.
The following is my vhost on the new 2.4 machine:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
        LogLevel info
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log combined
        <Directory /var/www/>
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The 2.2 machine uses the default Apache conf.  The .htaccess file that I use successfully on the 2.2 machine is as follows:

```
AuthName "Htaccess"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
Satisfy Any
<Limit GET POST>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from officeip
        Require valid-user
</Limit>
```

Which allows our office IP to view the contents and everyone else has to enter a user and password.  On Apache 2.2, this works the way I want it to.  If you go to the server's address or any script underneath the directory, you're prompted for a login.  On the 2.4 machine though, if you go to a specific script, it ask you to login.

Have there been changes to the way .htaccess files work in 2.4 and if so, how can I change mine to do what I want?

Comment: If you're down-voting, leave a comment so I know what I'm doing wrong -_-

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual (I did a search on the Apache site for `satisfy` and came across this link: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html#run-time) the access control system has changed.

I believe you can now do:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Htaccess"
# Optional line:
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
<RequireAll>
    RequireMethod GET POST
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip officeip
        Require valid-user
    </RequireAny>
</RequireAll>
```

Sources:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/auth.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authz_core.html#logic